# Microsoft Sharepoint Designer 2013 Preview encountered an errod during setup

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, error, installation

I'm trying to install sharepoint designer 2013.
It gives me this error without any further details.
I have office 2010 32 bit installed.

What is this problem about?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error? Which words in your question title are the error? Are you installing a preview version?

Comment: The error is just: Microsoft Sharepoint Designer 2013 Preview encountered an error during setup. Thats all :(

Comment: So, are you installing a Preview version? Why not install the  released version?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find the released version. I tried to install preview version cause that is the result when you search for SP Designer 2013. I'll let you know. Thanx

Comment: Thank you. I searched for SharePoint Designer Released Version and I installed it. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find the released version instead of the preview and install that.